# IllegalStateException : Not allowed inside a portlet

Tags: java, struts2, portlet, response.redirect, illegalstateexception

I have a problem and I need some help to fix it. I working in a web portal which makes use of Struts2 and Portlets (I don't have much knowledge on any of them). I have a page where a button is there and on clicking it i call an action which inturn call various methods . In one of the methods I should check for some conditions and then redirect to another server (For ex : www.google.com). For this redirection I am using below code.

```
ServletActionContext.getResponse().sendRedirect("www.google.com");
```

But when this line is encoutered an exception is being thrown as

```
java.lang.illegalStateException : Not allowed inside a portlet.
```

After searching in net I foundout that `sendRedirect()` cannot be called after invoking methods like

```
setPortletMode()
setWinddowState()
```

etc etc.

I want to know whether this is the problem or not. If yes then how to overcome it.

PS : Because of security reasons I cannot post the code and exception logs here.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do when you talk about "redirecting". Portlets aren't full Web pages, they're embedded components, and a redirect is something that's applied to an entire HTTP request.

Comment: Is it possible to do an entire HTTP request redirection from inside a Porlet..? That ia s portlet is there. And inside that a button. When I click on that button a new link should be opened in the browser and not inside the portlet.

Comment: @AnupNadahalli Then it's best done from JacaScript rather than sending a redirect.

Comment: Living not in the portlet context doesn't allowed to do it.

Comment: @Thihara Thanks for the help.. I redirected from JavaScript itself..